# Rabbitmq requeue all the message after restarted

Tags: rabbitmq

After the rabbitmq server or cluster is restarted, all the queue have recover all the message even the messages have be acked (from the point that rabbitmq server is started), and process all messages again.

Queue details

[image]

From my understanding, setting `persistenet` to false in the message arguments, the message will not survive if broker restart. Also, I have set `durabele` to false for the queue.

Did I missed any other settings?

Answer (score 1):

Making a message persistent true is fine as you do not want to loose message in case of rabbitmq restart. Secondly, it is also fine to make the queue durable so that you dont want to loose the queue in case of rabbitmq restart. I will suggest please check the message consumer code as it looks like it is not commiting the transaction on its side making the message available on the queue. What you can do is after consuming messages please stop the consumer and check on the RabbitMQ if the messages are still available on the queue. If the messages are still available on queue after stopping the consumer , then there must be some issue on the consumer code.